# how to dynamic chain a promise inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, chaining

I have the following exercise :

```js
let standInLine = (() => {
  return function(logAfter) {
    return function b(seconds) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`${seconds} has passed`)
          resolve(b(seconds));
        }, seconds * 1000);
      }) //what to do here to chain the promises
    }
  }
})();
{
  let politeLogAfter = standInLine(logAfter);
  politeLogAfter(5);
  politeLogAfter(3);
  politeLogAfter(4);
}
```

I need to chain the promises , in other words , I need to chain the returned promise dynamically , where I should add .then() inside the function standInLine but I dont know how to do that , any help ?
The result should be :

pause 5 seconds

log “5 seconds have passed”

pause 3 seconds

log “3 seconds have passed”

pause 4 seconds

log “4 seconds have passed”

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the result should be?

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single promise as a queue by always using `.then()` on it:

```js
let standInLine = (() => {
  // create a queue
  let queue = Promise.resolve();

  return function(logAfter) {
    return function b(seconds) {
      //add to the end of the queue
      queue = queue.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(`${seconds} has passed`)
          resolve(b(seconds));
        }, seconds * 1000);
      }))
    }
  }
})();
const logAfter = 10;
{
  let politeLogAfter = standInLine(logAfter);
  politeLogAfter(5);
  politeLogAfter(3);
  politeLogAfter(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sleep = (seconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, seconds * 1000)
  })
}

const standInLine = async(seconds) => {
  await sleep(seconds)
  console.log(`${seconds} has passed`)
}

const chain = async() => {
  await standInLine(5)
  await standInLine(3)
  await standInLine(2)
}

chain()
```